# Predictive dictionary text input API/framework for with iOS apps

Tags: ios, spelling

I have been looking for while for an 'predictive dictionary' that is used the iPhone and other other phones to increase text input accuracy by suggesting the words.

1. Does anyone know if such dictionary is available for Objective C/iOS?
2. Or a way/tools to create one from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider using `UITextChecker` ?