# How can I add selectable suggestion on textfield

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I'm not sure if I use the phrase correctly.

The function I want is that after user typed some characters (or clicked a button), a list will be shown under the textfield.

An easy example is Google search. After you typed "fb" or "faceb", it shows "facebook" in the suggestion list.

The content of the list is stored in an array, which comes from the return of web services.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Predictive dictionary text input API/framework for with iOS apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137655/predictive-dictionary-text-input-api-framework-for-with-ios-apps)

Comment: 1) Create a list of predictions.  2) Search the list.

Comment: Oh well, my question is more like to be about how do implement the GUI.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - UX is not for the "how to do something". That is what SO is for. UX is more for the "should I do something". I don't know why you think "how to implement the GUI" is a user experience question.

Comment: @Charles Boyung Thank you. I guess that's why my question was closed there...

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Sorry, I thought of "how to do" as in "how would it look and behave" and I missed the OPs comment on the question. I'll remove the comment to not confuse anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to intercept the keystrokes with `UITextView textViewDidChange`.  Then, with each keystroke, you implement the lookup algorithm and display your list of selections above or below the UITextView where the data entry is occurring.  The list has to somehow be "touchable" to select from it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how could I show the list? I found "UIPickerView", but I think there should be a simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial that shows how this can be done over at his [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values)

He creates a table below the text field that is touchable.

There is also a sample project there.